# Selenium Click method not working on an Xpath locator

Tags: xpath, selenium, selenium-ide

Folks,

My first time on Stack Overflow. Hope y'all can help ...

I'm trying to use Selenium to click on the 'Buy Now' button on an html page. Here's the HTML snippet:

```
</div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="buttonCheckout">Buy Now</a>
    <a href="#" class="buttonSoldout">Sold Out</a>
</div>
```

I used the Selenium IDE to get the correct Xpath locator but the click event always fails.

```
>> chk = "id('yui-gen2')/x:div[3]/x:div/x:a[1]"
=> "id('yui-gen2')/x:div[3]/x:div/x:a[1]"
>> @selenium.get_xpath_count(chk)
=> "1"

>> @selenium.click(chk)
**Error**

>> chk = "xpath = " + chk
=> "xpath = id('yui-gen2')/x:div[3]/x:div/x:a[1]"
>> @selenium.click(chk)
**Error**

The **Error** is:
selenium-client received failure from selenium server:
requested:
 cmd=click
 1=xpath = id('yui-gen2')/x:div[3]/x:div/x:a[1]
 sessionId=d4d6796b3c9749139621cd0cbcde80b2
received:
 "ERROR: Element xpath = id('yui-gen2')/x:div[3]/x:div/x:a[1] not found"
 called from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:67:in `timeout'
 enium::CommandError: ERROR: Element xpath = id('yui-gen2')/x:div[3]/x:div/x:a[1] not  found
```

I've tried some of the other suggestions on the forum - `@selenium.double_click(chk)`, `@selenium.fire_event(chk, 'click')` - but those give the same Element not found error.

I've also tried all kinds of permutations of the above, tried others Xpaths (`chk = "//a[@class='buttonCheckout']"`, `chk = "/descendant::a[@class='buttonCheckout']"`, `chk = "//a[@href='javascript:void(0)']"`.

In all of these cases, I believe I have found the right locator since the `get_xpath_count` method works but `click` always fails.

Any suggestions here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You haven't shown the complete XHTML document and thus there is no way for anyone to verify that the XPath expressions would select the desired node. Please edit your question and provide all the necessary information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is embarrassing but I figured it out ... the XPath locator was fine.

The issue was with the spaces in the statement:

```
chk = "xpath = " + chk
```

It should be:

```
chk = "xpath=" + chk
```

And then everything works nicely.

Newbies hah.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Error message "Element xpath = ... not  found" clearly states the real problem - so double click and fire event won't help.

You may try to install Selenium IDE plugin of Firefox, start recording and click on "Buy Now" button. Selenium IDE will automatically find some way to locate element. Also, it usually suggests several locator variants in drop-down list.

Also, you may try to use XPather / XPath checker plugins to find and check suitable xpath locators variants.